# How to deselect first row checkbox in Ext JS 3.4

Tags: checkbox, default, extjs3

How can I prevent the first checkbox from being selected upon loading of my grid (EditorGridPanel)
My problem is it always check the first row.

I'm using Ext JS 3.4.

code snippet:

```
 var chkboxSelModelUser = new com.thecompany.ux.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel();
 var userGrid = new com.thecompany.ux.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    store: that.userStore,     
    selModel: chkboxSelModelUser
    region:'center',
    margins: '0 5 5 5',
    frame: false,
    border: false,
    columns: [chkboxSelModelUser, new com.thecompany.ux.grid.RowNumberer()
    ... 
 ]...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use plain ExtJS 3.4 it shouldn't happen. Usually selecting default row is made in `viewready` event handler.

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ak3vB/1/

Comment: Thanks. It is now OK. I just have something in my code below that I overlooked that really selects the first row.